# BlueStacks on Windows 7 can't able to click otherthan maximize and close buttons

Tags: bluestacks

I have installed BlueStacks on Windows 7 (HP c510 laptop). I can't able to click any items in the app player. Only Maximize and close button on the bottembar is clickable. I have uninsatlled old version (Android 2.3.3) from my laptop for installing this new version. Old version just work fine. What was the problem with the new version ??